# Is a 1099 required when one freelancer hires another?

Tags: legal, usa

If I'm a freelancer but I need to hire another freelancer to help me on something, do I need to send the other person tax documents (W9) and report 1099 later on?

Answer (score 4):

IANAL. However according to the [IRS](http://www.irs.gov/uac/About-Form-1099MISC) you need to file a 1099-MISC if you made any of the following payments

> File this form for each person to whom you have paid during the year:
>
> - at least $10 in royalties or broker payments in lieu of dividends or tax-exempt interest;
> - at least $600 in rents, services (including parts and materials), prizes and awards, other income payments, medical and health care
>     payments, crop insurance proceeds, cash payments for fish (or other
>     aquatic life) you purchase from anyone engaged in the trade or
>     business of catching fish, or, generally, the cash paid from a
>     notional principal contract to an individual, partnership, or estate;
> - any fishing boat proceeds,
> - gross proceeds of $600, or more paid to an attorney during the year, or
> - withheld any federal income tax under the backup withholding rules regardless of the amount of the payment.

In your case, the operative one would be the $600 "cash paid from a notional principal contract to an individual" (second point above).

Note that this is cumulative, not per-payment. If you made 4 $200 payments to this person during a single tax year you would have to file.

Exemptions can be found [here](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Am-I-Required-to-File-a-Form-1099-or-Other-Information-Return)

> - You are not engaged in a trade or business.
> - You are engaged in a trade or business and
>
>   - the payment was made to another business that is incorporated, or
>   - the sum of all payments made to the person or unincorporated business is less than $600 in one tax year (unless the recipient is an
>       attorney or law form, see specific instructions for 1099-MISC for
>       further details).

In my personal opinion, if I was using Quickbooks or something similar, I'd just fill out the form anyway and send it off (with a copy to your supplier). They can decide whether or not to declare the income - but at least you are covered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you and they are in the US and you pay them $600 or more in one year.
You will need to file a summary report by a certain date and get the 1099 to them by a certain date. (I think January 30th)

Doing the form yourself is a MAJOR pain because, last I read, it has to be on a certain type of paper with a specific font in a certain way because a machine reads it (you couldn't just print it, I had to buy the forms at office depot then find a typewriter, that was at least 10 years ago so maybe that has changed.)

Anyhow - what I do now is use an online tax filing service, it's less than $5 to have them done and they file the summary for you plus send them to the freelancers.  The only thing I don't like about it is typing people's tax info into the Internet, but, what else are you gonna do?!

Comment: Didn't want to risk spamming, but if you are using quickbooks it can definitely [do the 1099's for you](http://quickbooks.intuit.com/prepare-1099/). And if you use it properly it can fill out most of your tax return as well.

Comment: Thanks, Good to know - I don't use QuickBooks, but I may switch to it in the future.